# How to print values stored in a cell as strings (whole words) in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, printf

For

```
A=[100;300;1000;240]
```

and

```
B=cell(8,1)
```

I have the following results stored in a B

```
[100]
[300]
[1000]
[240]
[100;300;240]
[100;1000]
[300;1000]
[100;300;1000]
```

I want to print these to display the output as :

```
choose first
choose second
choose third
choose fourth
choose first or second or fourth
choose first or third
.
.
etc
```

Basically, from the array `A=[100;300;1000;240]` , I want each value inside of it to be represented by a **string**, and **not one variable**. Any idea how to do this ?

---

note :

For my code, I want the user to input their own numbers in array **A**, and hence the length of **A** is variable and can be more than 4. The size of cell **B** also changes according to a formula, so it is not always fixed at size 8.

---

I would also appreciate a simple code, nothing too complex (unless necessary) as I don't have professional knowledge with matlab. A simpler code can help me understand and learn.

Comment: It can be done exhaustively. Basically you check if the content of cell i has occurred anywhere in cell 0 to i-1. If yes, return the index of the cell. I don't know a more efficient way. I will try to write the code later.

Comment: @Parag I am trying to find a way to do this but I'm getting nowhere .. Please do when you get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for mapping I would just use a [map object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html)

```
index_to_string = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet)
```

where

```
keySet = 1:20
valueSet = {'first'; 'second'; ...; 'twentieth'}
```

If `A` is available before printing, you can use the same `valueSet`, just cut it down to the size of `A`.

```
index_to_string = containers.Map(A,valueSet(1:length(A)))
```

Example:

```
G = cell(size(B))
for i = 1:length(B)
    out1 = 'choose ';
    if len(B{i}) == 1
        out1 = [out1, index_to_string(B{i})];
    else
        temp = B{i}
        for j=1:(length(temp)-1)
            out1 = [out1, index_to_string(temp(j)), ' or ' ];
        end
        out1 = [out1, index_to_string(temp(end))];
    end
    G{i} = out1
end
```

Comment: @NLed please try to communicate with people trying to help you. "I can't get this to work" is not it. Please explain what you did, what the error was, etc.  Another thing: try to write down the sequence of events you want to take place and logic behind it. Example: I want user to put numbers in A, then I calculate B and then I want to print for each line of B the positions  where the numbers from B are in matrix A. In pretty form. Is that it?

Comment: Oh my bad I thought I posted the error, I get : `Error using containers.Map The number of keys and values must be the same.` .. My example : `keySet = 1:4`  `valueSet = ['first', 'second','third','fourth']`

Comment: Might be I forgot something: you probably need a cell array: `valueSet = 'first', 'second','third','fourth'}`. I think what I suggested before only concatenates the strings and the result is one long string not an array os strings. Will update the answer.

Comment: Can you paste what the `size(valueSet)` returns? And sorry - there is a typo in the previous comment - the correct line should be `valueSet = {'first', 'second','third','fourth'}

Comment: Yes, I tried that and got `ans =     1    22` and for size(keySet) : `ans =    1     4` -- It is counting each letter rather than the whole string as one ...

Comment: I guess it is. My bad - checked documentation - use `;` between cells. `valueSet = 'first'; 'second'; 'third'; 'fourth'}`

Comment: Although I looked at the documentation, I missed that small tip !! Thanks ... However I now have another error, `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` ... This happens when I run `current_output_string = index_to_string(B(i,j))`

Comment: And where does that happen? constructing `index_to_string`?

Comment: Oh I edited my comment before u posted your question. size B for my current example as `7  1`

Comment: Is that from `B(i,j)` - what are `i` and `j`?

Comment: Oh am I supposed to put this in a loop ?? I just copied what you typed down and thought the map class takes care of this. (never used this before so I have no idea how this is exactly working - even after reading the documentation). -- I tried adding a for loop with i=1:4 .. I get `Error using containers.Map/subsref ` - `Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.`

Comment: As you might have guessed, I don't have Matlab here. Could you tell me what `index_to_string.KeyType` returns and what `class(B)` and `class(B(i,j))` return.

Comment: Hmm I get the same error .. `Error using containers.Map/subsref
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.` and `index_to_string.KeyType = double` and `Class(B)=cell` and `class(B(i,j))=cell` .. btw for my example, the cell B has (length(A),1) .. so j is not needed to iterate through columns.

Comment: Of course...I just looked at the contents of B and forgot it was a cell array. So you have to use curly braces - updated answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25733/discussion-between-dedek-mraz-and-nled)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it

```
function IChooseYouPikachu(Choices, Results)
% put in A for choices and B for results

%simple boolean to indicate whether a choice has been made already
answerChosen = 0;

for k = 1:length(Results)
    Response = 'choose';
    for m =  1:length(Choices)
        if any(Results{k} == Choices(m))
            if answerChosen
                Response = [Response ' or ' NumToOrd(m)];
            else
                answerChosen = 1;
                Response = [Response ' ' NumToOrd(m)];
            end
        end
    end
    fprintf('%s\n',Response);
    answerChosen = 0;
end

function ordinal = NumToOrd(number)
switch number
    case 1, ordinal = 'first';
    case 2, ordinal = 'second';
    case 3, ordinal = 'third';
    case 4, ordinal = 'fourth';
    otherwise, ordinal = 'out of index';
end
```

Comment: I get an error that says `Undefined function 'NumToOrd' for input arguments of type 'double'.` Also, can you not make this as a function, I prefer having it run without the need of functions.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is entirely based on `JaredS's` answer. I have just clarified your doubts.

Write this in some m-file.

```
Choices=A; Results=B;
%simple boolean to indicate whether a choice has been made already
answerChosen = 0;

for k = 1:length(Results)
    Response = 'choose';
    for m =  1:length(Choices)
        if any(Results{k} == Choices(m))
            if answerChosen
                Response = [Response ' or ' NumToOrd(m)];
            else
                answerChosen = 1;
                Response = [Response ' ' NumToOrd(m)];
            end
        end
    end
    fprintf('%s\n',Response);
    answerChosen = 0;
 end
```

Please write the following function in a separate file and put that in the same directory as the previous m-file. Then you should get an error saying: `"Undefined function 'NumToOrd' for input arguments of type 'double'."`

```
function ordinal = NumToOrd(number)
switch number
    case 1, ordinal = 'first';
    case 2, ordinal = 'second';
    case 3, ordinal = 'third';
    case 4, ordinal = 'fourth';
    otherwise, ordinal = 'out of index';
end
```

Comment: I get the result as  `choose          `, followed by blank .. what could be causing this ?

Comment: Its very difficult for me to tell this since this is not my code. But I can suggest you one thing for sure. Learn to debug. So go step by step into your program and you would find out why this is happening. It will help you in future too.